# is it possible to improve the "contains" filter for a view?

Tags: sql-server, view

I have a view like this in SQL Server:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[myUsers]
AS
    SELECT 
        T1.*, 
        STRING_AGG(gr.Name, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY gr.Name) AS MemberOf
    FROM     
        (SELECT 
             mu.Id, 
             CASE 
                 WHEN iu.ObjectGuid IS NULL 
                     THEN u.Username 
                     ELSE iu.SAMAccountName 
             END AS Username, 
             CASE 
                 WHEN iu.ObjectGuid IS NULL 
                     THEN u.FirstName 
                     ELSE iu.GivenName 
             END AS FirstName, 
             CASE 
                 WHEN iu.ObjectGuid IS NULL 
                     THEN u.LastName 
                     ELSE iu.LastName 
             END AS LastName, 
             CASE 
                 WHEN iu.ObjectGuid IS NULL 
                     THEN u.Email 
                     ELSE iu.Email 
             END AS Email, 
             CASE 
                 WHEN iu.ObjectGuid IS NULL 
                     THEN u.Phone 
                     ELSE iu.Telephone 
             END AS Phone, 
             CASE 
                 WHEN iu.ObjectGuid IS NULL 
                     THEN u.Mobile 
                     ELSE iu.Mobile 
             END AS Mobile, 
             CASE 
                 WHEN iu.ObjectGuid IS NULL 
                     THEN u.CompanyCode 
                     ELSE co.Code 
             END AS CompanyCode, 
             co.Name, 
             CASE 
                 WHEN iu.ObjectGuid IS NULL 
                     THEN 0 
                     ELSE 1 
             END AS IsNotMaster
         FROM 
             MasterUsers mu 
         LEFT JOIN 
             Users u ON u.Id = mu.UsersId 
         LEFT JOIN 
             InternalUsers iu ON iu.ObjectGuid = mu.ObjectsGUID 
         LEFT JOIN 
             Companies co ON co.name = iu.company
         WHERE 
             iu.ObjectGuid IS NULL OR iu.ModifiedStatus < 100) AS T1 
    LEFT JOIN 
        MasterUsers mu ON mu.Username = T1.Email 
    LEFT JOIN 
        UsersGroups ug ON ug.MasterUsersId = mu.Id 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Groups gr ON gr.Id = ug.GroupsId
    GROUP BY 
        t1.id, T1.Username, T1.FirstName, T1.LastName, T1.Email, 
        T1.Phone, T1.Mobile, T1.CompanyCode, T1.Name, T1.IsNotMaster
```

When I run it and filter by Username and `equal`, it's pretty fast (a few ms):

```
SELECT [Id]
    ,[Username]
    ,[FirstName]
    ,[LastName]
    ,[Email]
    ,[Phone]
    ,[Mobile]
    ,[CompanyCode]
    ,[Name]
    ,[IsNotMaster]
    ,[MemberOf]
FROM [dbo].[myUsers]
WHERE Username = 'testuser'
```

but if I use `contains` on Username, it become very slow (such as 3/4 seconds):

```
SELECT [Id]
    ,[Username]
    ,[FirstName]
    ,[LastName]
    ,[Email]
    ,[Phone]
    ,[Mobile]
    ,[CompanyCode]
    ,[Name]
    ,[IsNotMaster]
    ,[MemberOf]
FROM [dbo].[myUsers]
WHERE Username LIKE '%testuser%'
```

Where could I improve the query, in your opinion? Are indexes on the view is possible?

I could change the view itself or add/edit indexes, but not add the filtering (i.e. Username and `where`) inside it (since I call it wherever, for various purpose, and must be generic).

Comment: `LIKE` with a *leading* Wildcard isn't SARGable. Although an index on the column that `INCLUDE`s the other columns in the query *might* help the RDBMS if there are other columns in the table you are referencing, this would only be by means of that the pages the RDBMS needs to read are smaller. Considering, however, you're looking for "test users", then perhaps what you should really have is a [`bit`] column that denotes the user is a test user or not, which can then indexed and used in SARGable queries.

Comment: EAV strikes again! Perhaps reconsider that decision since that is the reason you need this logic, even if for just a subset of the information you currently have. And this `mu.Username = T1.Email` looks suspicious but only you know your schema.